# How to call a method? Keep getting an error saying "return type is void"

Tags: java

I am trying to call the method of "menu" but it says the return type is void?

I want the code in the method of menu to display when the sides is equal to 2?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class RecordDice {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int dSides, Sides;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many sides should the dice have?");
    Sides = s.nextInt();
    if (Sides == 2){
        return menu();
    }
}
  public String menu()
  {
    System.out.println("BLOODY WORK");
  }
}
```

Comment: `public static *void* main ..` but, as this is how `main` *must* be defined in Java to be the program entry-point, the question is: *why* try and return a String from it? (Also, the code needs to return from the `menu` method or declare it as void or there will be another error.)

Answer (score 3):

```
if(Sides == 2){
    menu();
}
```

Just provide the method name. Your `main()` is void and thus you need not return a value. Ot else, you can capture the value in a variable if you want to use it later.

```
if(Sides == 2){
    String val = menu();
}
```

But then your `menu()` method does not have a return statement at all, even though it has a `String` return type.

Also, the `menu()` method seems to be outside the `RecordDice`. Move it inside, to be able able to call it. And you have to make it `static` as well, since you're calling it in the `main()` method, which is `static`. You can't call a `non-static` method from a `static` one.

Comment: Hey, thanks this has helped but like you said its showing up as not having a return type.. how do i fix that problem?

Comment: @user2986734 - What is showing up as not having a return type?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args){ // here your return type is void
```

You can't return values from when return type void.

Change as follows

```
 if (Sides == 2){
   String val=menu();// now val assign the retuning value of menu()
  }
```

Comment: menu is not a static method

Comment: @javaBeginner then make it static. you know, you can't access non-static member inside static member. right?

Comment: yeh thats why I said menu is not static so how **String val=menu();** will work?